# Column Mismatch in UNION queries

Tags: sql, db2, union

I have columns A,B in Table 1 and columns B,C in Table 2.Need to perform Union between them .
For example : select A,B from Table 1 UNION select 0,B from Table 2.

I dont need this zero to solve the column mismatch.Instead is there any other solution?

Am asking the question by providing simple example . But in my case the table structure is very large and the queries are already built.Now I need to fix this union query by replacing this zero.(due to DB2 upgrade)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't exactly understand what you want to achieve. The `UNION` requires the same amount of columns. So you have to provide some dummy value. What about any other default value?

Comment: For that matter, the columns at least have to be convertible, too.   If `A` is a `DATE`, and you're providing just a `0`, the cast is going to fail.

Answer (score 3):

For two legs A and B in a union to be union compatible it is required that:

```
a) A and B have the same number of columns
b) The types for each column in A is compatible with the corresponding column in B
```

In your query you can use null that is part of every type:

```
 select a, b from T1 
 UNION 
 select null, b from T2
```

Under certain circumstances, you may have to explicitly cast null to the same type as A has (probably not in this case):

```
 select a, b from Table 1 
 UNION 
 select cast(null as ...), b from Table 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A column returned in a SQL result set can only have one data type. 
A union or union all results in rows from the first query and the rows of the second query (in case of union they are deduplicated).
So the first column of the first query needs to match the data type of the first column of the second query.

You can check this by running a describe:

```
describe select a,b from t1
```

If you work within a GUI (JDBC Connection) you could also use

```
call admin_cmd('describe select a,b from t1')
```

So if the some column does not match you have to explicitly cast the data types.